# Calculate price based on distinct count

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I am having trouble working out a measure (Revenue) in power bi.

I have a measure which is basically counting distinct values in a table (table 1). From this column I want to multiply the distinct count to get the total price (prices are in another table).

See below for an example

Table 1

```
Product DistinctCount Revenue (Measure I am trying to Calculate)
A           15         45.00
B           30         60.00
```

Prices Table

```
Product Price
A         3.00
B         2.00
```

At the moment the Revenue is calculating based on COUNT and not DISTINCTCOUNT.

Any help would be much appreciated. 
thanks!

Measures, Calculated Columns, Google

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have a relationship set up between these two tables on [Product]. If this is the case you can do something like this to create a calculated column:

```
Revenue =
CALCULATE (
    SUMX ( 'Table 1', 'Table 1'[DistinctCount] * RELATED ( 'Prices Table'[Price] ) )
)
```

If you are trying to create a table visual try the DAX below, where ID is just a transaction ID for each product in your 'Table 1':

```
Revenue =
VAR DistinctCountOfProductTransactions =
    CALCULATE ( DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Table'[Id] ) )
VAR Result =
    CALCULATE (
        DistinctCountOfProductTransactions * SUM ( Prices[Price] ),
        TREATAS ( VALUES ( 'Table'[Product] ), Prices[Product] )
    )
RETURN
    Result
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried the above, but it seems the multiplication is calculated on COUNT and not DistinctCount.

Comment: Thanks very much @StelioK, but, sadly it didn't do the trick. 
I don't understand as I have created the relationships. 
The distinctcount works but the price still calculates based on COUNT.

Comment: OK, I have a workaround. 
I have essentially added a number of occurences column. I then divided the unit price by occurence column to get a value where the subsequent measures now work.

Comment: That's so strange, the solution worked for me. Glad you figured it out!